# How can I configure load-balancing strategy for cluster Ip service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I see in the Service documentation
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-ipvs
that for Kube-proxy in IPVS proxy mode there are several load balancing modes supported:
"
IPVS provides more options for balancing traffic to backend Pods; these are:

```
rr: round-robin
lc: least connection (smallest number of open connections)
dh: destination hashing
sh: source hashing
sed: shortest expected delay
nq: never queue
```

Can those be set on cluster Ip service type and if yes how?
I think the default mode is round-robin but I don't know how (if possible) to change it.
And if anyone has any experience with those it would be greatly appreciated.
I guess the least connection or shortest expected delay would make the most sense, as there is no session to be kept.

Comment: The options that you mention are only for IPVS. This is an improvement to kube proxy default settings ( kube-proxy  iptables ) which uses round robin.  so,  if you want more options to balance the traffic to your backend, you will need to deploy the IPVS proxy. In this [link](https://dustinspecker.com/posts/ipvs-how-kubernetes-services-direct-traffic-to-pods/), you can  find a guide to deploy IPVS.